# reshaping square matrix into Nx3 with no diagonal elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, reshape

I have a NxN similarity matrix that I need to reshape into a N*N-N by 3 matrix.
I remove all the values from the diagonal.
The code I have working for this at the moment:

```
N=3;x=magic(N);
M=N*N-N;s=zeros(M,3);
j=1;
for i=1:N
 for k=[1:i-1,i+1:N]
 s(j,1)=i;
 s(j,2)=k;
 s(j,3)=x(i,k);
 j=j+1;
 end;
end;
```

So for this example the matrix s is:

```
1   2   1
1   3   6
2   1   3
2   3   7
3   1   4
3   2   9
```

I would like to avoid the for loops, since my matrices are rather big. I've been struggling with reshape and bsxfun, but can make it work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually after asking this somehow I also figure it out. I'll post it as well. It is slightly faster (on my machine) with N>5000, but not as elegant as chappjc solution:  tmp = bsxfun(@times,1:N, ones(N,1)); tmp = tmp(:);
s = [tmp, repmat([1:N]',N,1), reshape(x',[],1)];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility using [`eye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) and [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
N = 3; x = magic(N);
M = N*N-N;
s = zeros(M,3);
[s(:,2),s(:,1),s(:,3)] = find(~eye(N).*x.');
```

Alternatively, using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
[ii,jj] = ndgrid(1:size(x,1),1:size(x,2));
m = ii~=jj;
s = [jj(m) ii(m) x(sub2ind(size(x),jj(m),ii(m)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to speed up [chappjc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21191993/3019763)'s answer  for large N's by using logical indexing, but you will have to generate s(:,2) and s(:,1) separately:

```
N=3;x=magic(N);
x=x'
s(:,3) = reshape(x(~logical(eye(N))),[],1)
```